# How to install Python 3.7 packages to Docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am very new to docker. I am building a docker for the first time. I have created a Dockerfile and need to add python packages (specifically to emails). However I am getting an error while building the docker file.

```
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER <abc@gmail.com>
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir nibabel pydicom matplotlib pillow && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir med2image

RUN pip install pandas xlsxwriter numpy boto boto3 botocore
RUN pip install oauth2client urllib3 httplib2 email mimetypes apiclient
RUN pip install snowflake.connector

ENV APP_HOME /Users/username/
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles

RUN mkdir -p $APP_HOME/code/
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ENTRYPOINT [ "python"]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/e7/816030d3b0426c130040bd068be62b9213357ed02896f5d9badcf46d1b5f/email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "/tmp/pip-install-1m3cdjov/email/email/parser.py", line 10, in <module>
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cStringIO'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-1m3cdjov/email/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install oauth2client urllib3 httplib2 email mimetypes apiclient' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have installed these packages successfully in Pycharm and have no issues with it. I am not sure how to fix this in docker. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like that module is not compatible with python 3.x.

Comment: Will be interested to see a good solution to this. I've similar issues installing pip packages with Docker and Python.

I ended up running `docker exec -ti my_container bash`  then installing with `pip install`. After that I'd run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then install all the packages from that in the Dockerfile for all subsequent builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will face a similar issue with "mimetypes" module too. Even this is part of python base and you don't need to install it manually. Also, you can have all the required modules in a requirements.txt file and install them at once. For that, you need to copy the requirements file into the docker image before running install.

requirements.txt

```
nibabel
pydicom
matplotlib
pillow
med2image
pandas
xlsxwriter
numpy
boto
boto3
botocore
oauth2client
urllib3
httplib2
apiclient
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER <abc@gmail.com>
FROM python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I am pretty sure repository name must be lowercase. FROM alpine:3.7 can replace both lines 1 and 3 in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't make a mistake. The cStringIO module doesn't exist anymore. Just remove the email module from your pip install since it is already a part of python base and you should be good to go.

Comment: Now its giving me error with mimetypes . "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mimetypes (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mimetypes" Is this also a part of python base package ?